# passing multidimensional array from form in php

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I have a bit of a headache here. My problem is as follows.
I have three sites that I e-mail items to, all three sites have a couple of default mail addresses.
so on my form i create inputs with the existing addresses and allow the user to create more dynamically.
i might end up with the following

```
site 1 - address 1
site 1 - address 2

site 2 - address 1
site 2 - address 2
site 2 - address 3
```

etc

my inputs look like `<input type="text" name="email[]"/>`

i need to pass the site identifier and the inputted address to my php script and loop through it to add the list to the database

Comment: If you know that you only have 3 sites, why not `name="site1email[]"`, `name="site2email[]"`, and `name="site3email[]"`?

Comment: site items are dynamic, so could be any number at the end of the day, with associated addresses

Comment: So when you said "I have three sites that I e-mail items to", you really mean "I have a dynamic number of sites that I e-mail items to"?

Comment: You could also do `name="email[site1][]"`/`name="email[site2][]"`/etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the array key and also make it two dimensional:

```
name="site[1][]"
name="site[1][]"
name="site[2][]"
name="site[2][]"
```

Then loop through and use key and value:

```
foreach($_POST['site'] as $site => $addresses) { // $site is the number and $addresses is an array
    $address_list = implode(',', $adresses);     // or loop $addresses or whatever
}
```

There are a lot of possibilities depending on how is easiest to structure and access it in your particular case.

Comment: so if i understand this correctly i would have 'code' name="email[siteid][]". or as i will have it name="email[1][]".

Comment: Yes, that will work.  I used site because the number is the site number and it made more sense.

Comment: to access it in php i use echo $email[siteid][offest]. ;) so i managed to figure it out from what you said, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume a basic form like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
</form>
```

Your email fields would appear in PHP as the following:

```
$_POST['email'][0]
$_POST['email'][1]
```

As you can see, all email fields are neatly stored into the array `$_POST['email']`. PHP Does this automatically when appending `[]` to your input field names.

You can also nest them even deeper:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email[1][]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[1][]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[2][]" />
    ...
</form>
```

Now they would show up in `$_POST['email'][1][...]`, `$_POST['email'][2][...]` and so on.